# ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: c#, system.data.oracleclient

I create two table in my oracle (11g) database like this:

```
    create table "test" ("id" int);
    create table test ("id" int);
```

Then in my C# program there is a problem :

```
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(-myConnectionString-);
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from test;", conn);
    var v = command.ExecuteReader(); 
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from \"test\";", conn);
    var v = command.ExecuteReader();
```

for both command.ExecuteReader() I have an "ORA-00911: invalid character" error.

Comment: have you tried to execute this queries in some oracle client(either toad or pl-sql developer)?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal quite a few dialects of SQL allow `;` as a separator between queries, so it might be that rather than C# that it's being confused with.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Remove ; (semi-colon) from the end of SQL string

Comment: Just came accross. What if I need to execute 2 Update statements on 2 different tables on the same command? Putting semicolon produces an error.

Comment: its because the parameters are from a datareader and i need to execute 2 insert statements on 2 different tables while the datareader is reading.

Comment: I must say that I don't understant your scenario completly, better ask another question, and see this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.data.odbc/hHwYSbmsvqc

Comment: Sorry for swearing, but seriously wtf? Why wouldn't they accept semicolons in the query string? I wasted one and a half hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my very very simple db code.

Comment: Why can't Oracle just say which character is invalid in their error message?

Comment: I waste the whole afternoon to recognize my issue. I write multiple statements in a single command at firstly, so it's really a nightmare if a developer meet unfriendly 'invalid character' error message.

Comment: They don't tell you what character is invalid because, compared to MSSQL, Oracle is trash.

Answer (score 34):

In case other people wind up here looking for how to include multiple statements in a single command, you need to wrap your statements within **begin** and **end**. This will stop the invalid character errors due to the semi-colons. For example:

```
var command = new OracleCommand(@"
    begin
    select * from test;
    select * from test2;
    end;")
```

Comment: Old answer but very useful!

Comment: how to do multiple create?

Comment: When I try to use this I get the following exception: "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: just tried it and came to the conclusion that this **does not work for DDL statements** as are in OP. if you need to create tables, views, procedures etc., the only solution seems to be in the accepted answer, remove the last semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using semicolon in the query...It just be taken as invalid character.....
You have to remove the semicolon(;) from the query and do like this:

```
   OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(-myConnectionString-);
   conn.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from test", conn);
    var v = command.ExecuteReader(); 
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from \"test\"", conn);
    var v = command.ExecuteReader();
```

For more detail of this error, you can read [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00911_invalid_character.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't this guy's problem, but hopefully this will help someone out there:

I often have this problem with single quotes hidden inside inline comments, like so:

```
select foo 
from bar
where 
/* some helpful comment with a "can't" or somesuch */
baz='qux'
```

The unmatched single quote in the comment causes all kinds of drama, and oracle doesn't go out of its way to help you figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the *sqldatasource* parameter `?` with `:Column_name` in the `delete`, `update` and `insert` commands.

Comment: Are you asking a question or giving an answer here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.