# Oracle ORA-00911: invalid character Delete Command

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database from C#.

My code:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailMessage>(email.BodyText.Text);

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = Connection;

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
string output = new string(emailMessage.Command.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());

cmd.CommandText = output;
cmd.Connection = con;
ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the error on `ExecuteNonQuery` where is the invalid character

Error details

> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-00911: invalid character
>
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at SysConfig.Service1.ReadEmails() in C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\SysConfig\SysConfig\Service1.cs:line 126
> at SysConfig.Service1.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\SysConfig\SysConfig\Service1.cs:line 41
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

Query is sent through a JSON object:

```
{
  "Title": "sql",
  "Connection": "",
  "Command": "delete from USERLOG where id=6",
  "Result": false
}
```

the log (json object and output )

[image: LOG]

My Question is not duplicate with [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262145/ora-00911-invalid-character) the post talks about a semi colon in the end i do not have a semi colon

Query on Toad

[image: Query]

Comment: Can you share the debug error log?

Comment: i have updated the code and added Error Details

Comment: Please share the code for query as well. (CommandText )

Comment: Added the Query

Comment: what is the value return by this code??? string output = new string(emailMessage.Command.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());

Comment: Seems like the string value being passed into the cmd.CommandText is not well formatted.

Comment: the output string should be removing all non chars ??

Comment: Is column `id` in the database declarated as integer or number?

Comment: id Column is number

Comment: are you sure that output variable is started with 'delete from' ? Maybe the query in the list is wrong?
This query should be alright if id is numeric type, problem is probably in output variable.

Comment: t though of the same thing so i wrote string output = new string(emailMessage.Command.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
which should remove any invisible character

Comment: Your string output should ONLY contain "delete from USERLOG where id=6". For the moment, comment those codes and pass plain text ("delete from USERLOG where id=6") to your cmd.CommandText and run the code and see.

Comment: the string come from json object so i wrote string output = new string(emailMessage.Command.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
 it should remove any strange chars

Comment: I'd love to know the use case for this: you are taking a JSON object from an email and forwarding it straight to an Oracle server with no checking??

Comment: there is checking 1- the email subject must include the word sql - email contents must be json object with the format on the post

Comment: i used cmd.CommandText = "Delete from USERLOG where id=6;Commit;"; but still give the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00911: invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262145/ora-00911-invalid-character)

Comment: no my command does not include semi colon please see the image

Comment: In your last comment it did. If you manually run `delete from USERLOG where id=6` on your Oracle DB, do you get that error too? Check if the string has a non-standard encoding or the characters are 2-byte size each.

Comment: string output = new string(emailMessage.Command.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray()); isn't this command remove non-standard encoding characters - command run on DB - see photo on post

Comment: @MaherKhalil, I'm talking about a string which could be Unicode (2 bytes per char) or UTF32 (4 per char), that doesn't make every char a control character. The string might look ok but after each character you have null characters. If you copy the command that works on Toad and paste it here: `cmd.CommandText = "delete from userlog where id=6";`, does it fail?

Comment: when i added it as a fixed string it worked

Comment: Great, now all you have to do is compare the strings. I don't think the uppercase could be the issue, but check just in case (I don't have much experience with Oracle).

Comment: first the upper case is not a problem in oracle even if it is it should give error invalid table name or invalid column name , second it is the same string i think it is some html string which is not visible when extract the commend from email i think what i need is some code remove all non char from the string including html tags

Comment: By debugging you should be able to easily find out the differences between the strings. You could play with `str.ToCharArray()` or `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)`. Or remove parts of both strings until they are equal, to find where the difference is.